# QML TableView with dynamic width columns

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I have created a `TableView` in PySide2 Qt 5.13.0.  I want a `TableView` to fill the width of the parent item, but it will not resize the columns unless I drag the table.  From the start of the program, I want the columns to be wider.

[image]

main.py

```py
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

from table_model import TableModel

import qml_rc  # noqa: F401


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    qmlRegisterType(TableModel, "TableModel", 1, 0, "TableModel")

    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

import TableModel 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        showMaximized()
    }

    TableView {
        id: tableView
        clip: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: TableModel {}
        topMargin: columnsHeader.implicitHeight
        columnWidthProvider: function () { return tableView.width / tableView.model.columnCount(); }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: tableView.columnWidthProvider()
            implicitHeight: 40

            Text {
                text: display
            }
        }

        Row {
            id: columnsHeader
            y: tableView.contentY
            z: 2

            Repeater {
                model: tableView.columns > 0 ? tableView.columns : 1

                Rectangle {
                    width: tableView.columnWidthProvider()
                    height: 60
                    clip: true

                    Label {
                        id: headerText
                        width: parent.width
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                        text: tableView.model.headerData(modelData, Qt.Horizontal)
                        elide: Text.ElideRight
                        clip: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

table_model.py

```py
from typing import Any, Optional

from PySide2.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex, QObject, Qt

from table import Table


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent: QObject = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model_data = Table(
            ["This", "Is", "A", "Test", "Of", "Headers"],
            [
                ["A", 1, 2, "B", "C", "D"],
                ["E", 3, 4, "F", "G", "H"],
                ["I", 5, 6, "J", "K", "L"],
                ["M", 7, 8, "N", "O", "P"],
                ["A", 1, 2, "B", "C", "D"],
                ["E", 3, 4, "F", "G", "H"],
                ["I", 5, 6, "J", "K", "L"],
                ["M", 7, 8, "N", "O", "P"],
                ["A", 1, 2, "B", "C", "D"],
                ["E", 3, 4, "F", "G", "H"],
                ["I", 5, 6, "J", "K", "L"],
                ["M", 7, 8, "N", "O", "P"],
                ["A", 1, 2, "B", "C", "D"],
                ["E", 3, 4, "F", "G", "H"],
                ["I", 5, 6, "J", "K", "L"],
                ["M", 7, 8, "N", "O", "P"],
                ["A", 1, 2, "B", "C", "D"],
                ["E", 3, 4, "F", "G", "H"],
                ["I", 5, 6, "J", "K", "L"],
                ["M", 7, 8, "N", "O", "P"],
                ["A", 1, 2, "B", "C", "D"],
                ["E", 3, 4, "F", "G", "H"],
                ["I", 5, 6, "J", "K", "L"],
                ["M", 7, 8, "N", "O", "P"],
                ["A", 1, 2, "B", "C", "D"],
                ["E", 3, 4, "F", "G", "H"],
                ["I", 5, 6, "J", "K", "L"],
                ["M", 7, 8, "N", "O", "P"],
                ["A", 1, 2, "B", "C", "D"],
                ["E", 3, 4, "F", "G", "H"],
                ["I", 5, 6, "J", "K", "L"],
                ["M", 7, 8, "N", "O", "P"],
                ["A", 1, 2, "B", "C", "D"],
                ["E", 3, 4, "F", "G", "H"],
                ["I", 5, 6, "J", "K", "L"],
                ["M", 7, 8, "N", "O", "P"],
            ])

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
        return len(self._model_data.rows)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
        return len(self._model_data.headers)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role=Qt.DisplayRole) -> Optional[Any]:
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        if not self.checkIndex(index, QAbstractTableModel.CheckIndexOption.IndexIsValid):
            return None

        return self._model_data.rows[index.row()][index.column()]

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation, role) -> Optional[str]:
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        if section < 0 or section >= len(self._model_data.headers):
            return None

        return self._model_data.headers[section]

    def reset_with_data(self, model_data: Table) -> None:
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._model_data = model_data
        self.endResetModel()
```

table.py

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, List


@dataclass
class Table:
    headers: List[str]
    rows: List[List[Any]]
```

qml.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Run:

```
pipenv run pyside2-rcc -o qml_rc.py qml.qrc
pipenv run python main.py
```

Comment: provide a [MRE], you indicate that you are using a ColumnLayout but in your code I don't see it

Comment: Updated with complete example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#row-heights-and-column-widths) points out:

> ### Row heights and column widths
>
> When a new column is flicked into view,
>   TableView will determine its width by calling the columnWidthProvider
>   function. TableView itself will never store row height or column
>   width, as it's designed to support large models containing any number
>   of rows and columns. Instead, it will ask the application whenever it
>   needs to know.
>
> TableView uses the largest implicitWidth among the items as the column
>   width, unless the columnWidthProvider property is explicitly set. Once
>   the column width is found, all other items in the same column are
>   resized to this width, even if new items that are flicked in later
>   have larger implicitWidth. Setting an explicit width on an item is
>   ignored and overwritten.
>
> Note: The calculated width of a column is discarded when it is flicked
>   out of the viewport, and is recalculated if the column is flicked back
>   in. The calculation is always based on the items that are visible when
>   the column is flicked in. This means that it can end up different each
>   time, depending on which row you're at when the column enters. You
>   should therefore have the same implicitWidth for all items in a
>   column, or set columnWidthProvider. The same logic applies for the row
>   height calculation.
>
> **If you change the values that a rowHeightProvider or a
>   columnWidthProvider return for rows and columns inside the viewport,
>   you must call forceLayout. This informs TableView that it needs to use
>   the provider functions again to recalculate and update the layout.**
>
> Since Qt 5.13, if you want to hide a specific column, you can return 0
>   from the columnWidthProvider for that column. Likewise, you can return
>   0 from the rowHeightProvider to hide a row. If you return a negative
>   number, TableView will fall back to calculate the size based on the
>   delegate items.
>
> Note: The size of a row or column should be a whole number to avoid
>   sub-pixel alignment of items.
>
> The following example shows how to set a simple columnWidthProvider
>   together with a timer that modifies the values the function returns.
>   When the array is modified, forceLayout is called to let the changes
>   take effect:
>
> ```
> TableView {
>     id: tableView
>
>     property var columnWidths: [100, 50, 80, 150]
>     columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return columnWidths[column] }
>
>     Timer {
>         running: true
>         interval: 2000
>         onTriggered: {
>             tableView.columnWidths[2] = 150
>             tableView.forceLayout();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So in this case when the width of the TableView changes you should call [`forceLayout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#forceLayout-method). In my case (Qt 5.13.1, PySide2 5.13.1, Linux) I also had to set a width and height to the ApplicationWindow:

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

import TableModel 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        showMaximized()
    }

    width: 640
    height: 480


    TableView {
        id: tableView
        clip: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: TableModel{}
        topMargin: columnsHeader.implicitHeight

        columnWidthProvider: function (column) { 
            return tableView.model ? tableView.width/tableView.model.columnCount() : 0
        }

        onWidthChanged: tableView.forceLayout()

        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: tableView.columnWidthProvider(column)
            implicitHeight: 40
            Text {
                text: display
            }
        }

        Row {
            id: columnsHeader
            y: tableView.contentY
            z: 2
            Repeater {
                model: tableView.columns > 0 ? tableView.columns : 1
                Rectangle {
                    width: tableView.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
                    height: 60
                    clip: true

                    Label{
                        id: headerText
                        width: parent.width
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                        text: tableView.model ? tableView.model.headerData(modelData, Qt.Horizontal): 0
                        elide: Text.ElideRight
                        clip: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, this won't work with 5.13.0 due to a bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77459

Comment: Will this work if you change a provided column/row size from zero (hidden) to non-zero? I tried this and seems like even calling `forceLayout()` does not make the column appear.